# Find a vector from this equation

Tags: vectors

I have a directional vector $L_d$, that is the last direction that something has been moved. 
This vector is normalized. I also have the target point $T$ of this directional vector.
The problem is, how do I find the origin $O$ of this movement?
I.e. how to find $O$ from this equation: $L_d = \frac{T-O}{\|T-O\|_2}$

If this is even possible, I gladly accept every answer.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you cannot: that equation is satisfied for all vectors in the form $O=T-\lambda L_d$ for some $\lambda>0$.

Comment: The only thing I got out of this was 
$O = T-L_d\cdot \|T-O\|_2$. 
So $\lambda = \|T-O\|_2$.  But this knowledge doesn't really help in solving this equation.
Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: $\lambda=\lVert T-O\rVert_2$ is basically just the fact that your $L_d$ is normalised. @Danjohles